# Can deno emmit events on console input?

Tags: io, deno

The following code works in node by (i think) creating a readline interface and binding any line events to the callback function provided, Its a really nice non-blocking way to get user input, Does Deno have something similar? Every example Ive seen waits until the user types something instead of reacting to it.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.on('line',(x) => {
    switch(x){
      case "help":
        help()
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Any asynchronous function in JavaScript can be used in a non-blocking manner by not awaiting the returned `Promise`. e.g. Using an immediately invoked asynchronous function expression:

```ts
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/io/mod.ts";

(async function() {
  for await (const line of readLines(Deno.stdin)) {
    switch (line) {
      case "help":
        help();
        break;
    }
  }
})();
```

To emit an event, you can extend [`EventTarget`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#EventTarget) and dispatch instances of [`CustomEvent`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#CustomEvent) but if your use case is simple enough you can keep the code inline in the for loop.

See also:

- https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/io#readlines
- https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.stdin